# Minecraft Servers won't Connect at all

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

So, I have a legal full version of Minecraft, version 1.8.7, running Windows XP SP2, whenever I try to connect to a server, it does not connect.

When connecting to Hypixel, I get:

`Connection Lost
 Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter ´directory´ is not a directory`

On RebornCraft, I get:

`Connection Lost 
 Disconnected`

I know that my firewall is not the issue as I have played on these same servers previously. I tried typing in the server address again with no luck.

Also, my server ping is perfect:
[image: Server ping is perfect and yet I can't connect...]

Images showing the issue (Full size: [**1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxb6.png), [**2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuAUZ.png)):
[image: Random java error]
[image: Disconnected]

Comment: I found a bugtracker entry with the same error as the one you got at Hypixel: [MC-81082](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-81082). Although it is marked as "fixed", try the workaround: Create a folder called `server-resource-packs` in your `.minecraft` folder and try again.

Comment: If the above does not work, backup your saves and whatever else you deem important (resourcepacks, modded versions, etc.) and delete the entire `.minecraft` folder to force a reinstall of the game.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those worked. I did exactly what you said but they failed.

Answer (score 1):

Manually create the directory .minecraft/server-resource-packs, to fix
And, the

> Connection Lost  
> Disconnected

is just a small bug. Reinstalling Minecraft Should do the trick.

Comment: I fixed it, it was just the auto login bug...

Comment: Well, alright! I'm glad you got the problem fixed.